# How can I confirm a PayPal payment was executed successfully?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm working on an automated Item Mall that uses PayPal to process payments.

I currently execute a payment like so...

```
$execution = new \PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution();
$execution->setPayerId($request['PayerID']);
foreach($payment->transactions as $transaction)
{
    $execution->addTransaction($transaction);
}

try
{
    $result = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);
}
catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex)
{
    dd($ex);
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    dd($ex);
}
```

My question is... how can I confirm that the payment was executed successfully and that the money was entered into my PayPal account?

I'm assuming I have to do something with the $result variable... but what? The PayPal PHP SDK Documentation Sample just gets the Payment again using the original PaymentID... but that doesn't confirm I have received the money.

Comment: Why not var_dump($result) and see what's returned? Also you should be using IPN as well: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Comment: I did that, only thing that looks useful is the "state" that says it was approved. But the approved state is set prior to the execution... I use IPN but the items are automatically delivered to the user which is why I need to be able to auto confirm the sale was a success.

Comment: Auto-deliver the items to the user based on the IPN response, not based on the checkout response IMO.

Comment: If you want to check if something is successful or not, use `if/else`.

Comment: It's possible to edit the POST data coming out of the checkout, to only make a 0.01 cent charge, and have that return as a completed payment, so you have to check to make sure the amount matches the product amount as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Instant Payment Notification](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)

First you must [configure](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/) your PayPal account

Answer (score -1):

You will not be able to do that as, the transaction is an instruction rather than a live transaction. The funds will not show in your account until after the funds have gone through the clearing bank.